# Polling vs interrupts?

Tags: microcontroller, interrupt, fifo

Say you have a device with a 32 depth FIFO in which data from an ADC is stored after a conversion is finished. You can trigger an interrupt each time there are X samples in the FIFO and go grab the data from it.

When the interrupt triggers, a bit in the interrupt register on the device is set and the interrupt line is asserted.

So my questions is this: Is polling the interrupt register to go grab the data any different functionally from using the interrupt line? Are there any timing problems or anything I should be aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not really clear what you mean by "functionally".

The advantage of polling the interrupt register is that you can make sure you only get data from the ADC when your code is in the perfect state to handle it. This can simplify the code design significantly. The advantage of being interrupted is that you do not waste time checking the register when there's no data ready yet and it's less likely that you'll get busy doing something else and let the FIFO overflow.

Both approaches can make sense.

Typically, you would use an interrupt handler that copies the results into a larger software FIFO and poll the software FIFO. This ensures that data is not lost if your high-level code gets busy for longer than it takes to fill the FIFO. But if your code is simple enough that that's not an issue, this extra complexity doesn't buy you much.

Answer (score 1):

They are functionally the same.  Interrupts make it easier to do other things while you are waiting, but you can do other things while waiting and polling as well.  "It depends" but either one could be more deterministic, depends on the instruction set, the processor and what else you are doing while waiting.

There is no right answer, both work generally if the logic is designed to allow both to work equally, each has its pros and cons.  Polling usually means you are not doing anything else or have plenty of time.  On the other hand polling this could be what you do in the foreground and interrupts from other things in the background.

There are and can be successful real time or embedded or deterministic designs that are polling based and ones that are interrupt based.  In both cases you have to do your system engineering and understand all the tasks you need to do the best and worst cases for each, which has a higher priority for various things (you might have more than one things that are very important for different reasons and have to manage that).  A poll based design you have to walk all the paths and insure that all paths meet the requirements of everything in the design.  For interrupt the same deal just the paths are much harder to see.

Comment: I've voted this down because although it answers the question as written, I'm not sure the question was intended as written, and I feel this answer confuses matters. David Schwartz's answer I think better deals with it.

Answer (score 1):

BASIS FOR COMPARISON    INTERRUPT vs POLLING

Basic - Device notify CPU that it needs CPU attention.  CPU constantly checks device status whether it needs CPU's attention.

Mechanism   -An interrupt is a hardware mechanism.  Polling is a Protocol.

Servicing   -Interrupt handler services the Device. CPU services the device.

Indication  -Interrupt-request line indicates that device needs servicing.  Comand-ready bit indicates the device needs servicing.

CPU -CPU is disturbed only when a device needs servicing, which saves CPU cycles.   CPU has to wait and check whether a device needs servicing which wastes lots of CPU cycles.

Occurrence  -An interrupt can occur at any time.    CPU polls the devices at regular interval.

Efficiency  -Interrupt becomes inefficient when devices keep on interrupting the CPU repeatedly.

Polling becomes inefficient when CPU rarely finds a device ready for service.

Example  -Let the bell ring then open the door to check who has come.   Constantly keep on opening the door to check whether anybody has come.

Answer (score 0):

Polling means you won't know when the data is ready, but you can get it when you are ready. You'll have to tell your program how to wait for the data. Meanwhile, the interrupt triggers instantly when the data is ready, and the interrupt handler can fetch the data before the next instruction completes.

Interrupts were actually created to help solve the polling problem. No need to guess when the data is ready, the computer will tell you *and*, if you can set the interrupt handler, prepare it for execution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would advise you always use your own FIFO buffer, and either fill it inside the port interrupt, or when polling inside the timer interrupt. Since a FIFO can be easily implemented as a lock-less thread-safe collection (presuming one writer, one reader), it's a no brainer.

When you have this FIFO in place, it's almost the same whichever approach you take.

Having said that, if you do opt for timer based polling, make sure you **calculate the speed at which you need to clear the buffer**; i.e. a 32 byte hardware FIFO will get filled in ~2.8ms at 115200 baud rate, so in this case you will probably need at least a 1ms timer to read whatever is in the queue.